# Mapping object with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have my classes that looks like this :

```
public class Student{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Course{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Date Hour { get; set; }
}
```

And i want to map the Student class to the following one using **AutoMapper**

```
public class StudentModel{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public StudentProperties Properties { get; set; }
}
```

where StudentProperties is the remaining properties of the student class

```
public class StudentProperties{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

based on the AutoMapper documentation (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) we can use custom resolver to solve destination member while performing the mapping.
But i don't want to add new class for the resolver.

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to perform the mapping by just doing simple configuration like this :

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentProperties>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentModel>();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option that would work for you and would use `AutoMapper` for both `StudentModel` and `StudentProperties`:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentProperties>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Properties,
            opt => opt.ResolveUsing(Mapper.Map<StudentProperties>));
});
```

Here, we're making use of `ResolveUsing`, but using the `Func<>` version in order to avoid creating a new class. This `Func<>` is just `Mapper.Map` itself, which already knows how to map from `Student` to `StudentProperties`.

Comment: this works fine, thanks. but what if i have a property : `public Employee Teacher  { get; set; }` in the **student class** and i want to map it with another property `public EmployeeModel TeacherProperties  { get; set; }` in the **StudentModel class** ?

Comment: I finally find a solution for the question above, by adding the following code `.ForMember(dest => dest.TeacherProperties , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Teacher ));` under the config `cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentModel>()`. But i dont know if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to do something like that

```
CreateMap<Student, StudentModel>()
            .ForMember(dist => dist.Properties,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<StudentProperties>(src)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentModel>()
    .ForMember(
        x => x.Properties,
        x => x.ResolveUsing((src) => {
            return new StudentProperties(){
                Name    = src.Name,
                Courses = src.Courses,
                Address = src.Address
            }));
```

[Working Fiddle here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eBziC6)

Comment: this can work but i dont want to do the mapping property per property.